# ASP.NET Web Form Model Binding - Default Values on Insert

Tags: asp.net, model-binding

I have run into a catch 22 with default vales using model binding.
The tutorial from Tom FitzMacken has the following Insert:

```
public void addStudentForm_InsertItem()
{
    var item = new Student();

    TryUpdateModel(item);
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        using (SchoolContext db = new SchoolContext())
        {
            db.Students.Add(item);
            db.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
}
```

BUT if you have a required field that is not in your UI, say a CreatedDate field, the TryUpdateModel will fail validation.

I can't see how to assign a value to it before calling TryUpdateModel = stuck.

Answer (score 0):

Before you call `TryUpdateModel(item);` you can set the required field. To continue with your example of a `CreatedDate` field (let's assume it's DateTime):

```
var item = new Student();
//set the value here
item.CreatedDate = DateTime.Today;//.Now if you need the timestamp

//required field now has value, this should succeed
TryUpdateModel(item);
```

Another option, if you're in C# 6, you should be able to provide a default value to the property in your model:

```
public DateTime CreatedDate { get; set; } = DateTime.Today;
```

Comment: item.CreatedDate = DateTime.Today sets the value BUT
TryUpdateModel(item) then refreshes all values (even if not on your UI)

Comment: @DerekMcLachlan call `item.CreatedDate = DateTime.Today;` after `TryUpdateModel(item);`

Comment: Thanks @Drew but TryUpdateModel(item) validates & fails because of missing required date, so you can't set the value after TryUpdateModel.

For now I am sticking with putting it in my UI.

This is my first question so I am stumbling around. I edited my question, do you have any ide how to get the static DV value out of the generated class & into my partial class?

Answer (score 0):

Use view models and avoid the issue. Yes, you have a but extra work in mappi ng to entities, but you never have missing validations. The view model contains only the fields that will be coming in to that request.

Answer (score 0):

Static Default Value:

There is a  System.ComponentModel.DefaultValueAttribute but the documentation says
"A DefaultValueAttribute will not cause a member to be automatically initialized with the attribute's value. 
You must set the initial value in your code."

I tried the suggested code with the get\set & it did not set set the DV!

Then I added this 1 line to the model generated from the database.
(I am using code first from database, as that is where i do all my database design)

```
public tblInvestor()
this.Investor_ContactMethod = "Email"
```

**THIS WORKS** for a static default value & validates on a required field.
BUT it's in the generated class & I can't figure out how to get it into my seperate partial class with my Metadata?
Can not declare another public tblInvestor() - *so how\where to put it?*

DateTime Default Value:

Resigned to either putting it on the UI.
Or making it not required & setting it between TryUpdateModel & SaveChanges.